# Quadrilaterals in Affine Spaces

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry

I have this definition of quadrilateral in my notes:

Suppose we have a real affine space. We consider four points $A,B,C,D$ forms a quadrilateral if this points are included in the same plane and if we choose any three of them, they are not included in the same line. The points $A,B,C,D$ are the quadrilateral vertices, segments $AB, BC, CD, DA$ are the quadrilateral sides and segments $AC, BD$ are the quadrilateral diagonals.

Following the definition, I started to do some sketches and I found this strange situation:

[image]

**NOTE:** The points $A,B,C,D$ in the picture satisfies all the requirements of the definition. Then, we can say $AB, BC, CD, DA$ are the sides (painting in red) and $AC, BD$ are the diagonals (painting in pink)

But there is something strange about this picture. This is not the conventional idea that I have in my mind of a quadrilateral because there are two different regions!!

My question is the following:

Are there any mistakes in my definition of quadrilateral? Or maybe this picture represents a pathological type of quadrilateral that I don't know nothing about it?

Comment: No, your definition is good. You are here in a case where you have a [self intersecting quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_self-intersecting_polygons), whereas you are used to so called "simple" quadrilaterals. See [here](https://tikz.net/quadrilaterals/) as well.

Comment: Thank you! I have understood it now! But it is strange to me, I never imagine could exist self intersecting quadrilaterals.